How to add placeholder on property from custom type in Alfresco?
I am using Alfresco SDK and have custom type "arc:archive", which has property year "arc:year". In share-config-custom I have added this code
 <field id="arc:godina" >
                  <control template="/org/alfresco/components/form/controls/number.ftl">
            <control-param name="placeholder">2024</control-param>
        </control>
    </field>

but with no result.
I would be very grateful, if somebody knows what is the issue.

In control-param tag you can use only things that is in FTL template. For number.ftl look at github source for share -> "placeholder" is not there so you cant use it.
https://github.com/Alfresco/share/blob/master/web-framework-commons/src/main/resources/alfresco/site-webscripts/org/alfresco/components/form/controls/number.ftl
